# Redirecting stderr to file and stdout to console

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, stdout, stderr, console-redirect

```
dcc  -tPPCE200Z4VEN:simple -Xdialect-ansi -XO -g3 -Xsize-opt -Xsmall-data=0 -Xno-common -Xnested-interrupts -Xdebug-dwarf2 -Xdebug-local-all -Xdebug-local-cie -Xdebug-struct-all -Xforce-declarations -ee1481 -Xmacro-undefined-warn -Xlink-time-lint -W:as:,-l -Wa,-Xisa-vle -Xsmall-const=0 -Xforce-prototypes -Xpass-source -Xkeep-assembly-file -c -Xlint -Xenum-is-best -Xinline=0 -Xaddr-sconst=0x11 -Xaddr-sdata=0x11  -DDISABLE_MCAL_INTERMODULE_ASR_CHECK -DOSDIABPPC -DSC667349 -DFLASH_START -DV_SUPPRESS_EXTENDED_VERSION_CHECK -DV_USE_DUMMY_STATEMENT=STD_OFF -DEU_DISABLE_ANSILIB_CALLS -DMCAL_CER_VALIDATION -DOsAppMode=OSAPPMODEDEFAULT -DSKIP_MAGIC_NUMBER -DRTE_MICROSAR_PIM_EXPORT -DMEMIF_FAST_NVM_ACTIVATED=STD_ON -DESCLmgr_IsENABLED -DESCLmgr_CANrouting_RESvalidity=1 -DFEE_SWITCH_NOT_CONFIG_BLOCKS=STD_OFF -DFILL_NOINIT_WITH_ZERO -Dsrc -ID:\project\src -ID:\project\obj -E D:\project\src\hello.c 1> D:\project\obj\hello.i 2>&1
```

I am preprocessing a .c file (compiler wind river mpc ), then the stdout is redirected in the .i file and from the .i file, the .pp file is construcred. After that, I am redirecting the stderr to console (`2>&1`). Check the redirection at the end of the command line above.

I know there are a lot of question on this topic, but I am doing the correct redirectioning, yet the error appear in the .pp file:

`# 4 D:\project\src\hello.c", line 5: error (dcc:1573): Only Debug builds are supported`

Is this error actually from the stdout, can't it be splitted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`2>&1` doesn't mean "redirect stderr to console", it means "redirect stderr to the same place as stdout currently goes". If you do the redirections in the other order -- `2>&1 1>hello.i` instead of `1>hello.i 2>&1` -- then you will get the effect I believe you are looking for.

You need to think of the redirections happening one at a time. If you say `1>hello.i 2>&1` then this happens:

- First, stdout is redirected to `hello.i`.
- Then stderr is redirected to the current destination of stdout, namely `hello.i`.

But if you say `2>&1 1>hello.i` then this happens:

- First, stderr is redirected to the current destination of stdout, namely the console.
- Then stdout is redirected to `hello.i`.

Comment: Now it makes sense! Thanks for the detailed explanation and for the explicit compare between my problem and the real solution!

Comment: Even with this solution it won't make the redirection, my assumption is that stdout and stderr are both compacted in stdout...

Comment: That's strange. It works for me, both in a Unix shell where this syntax originated and on the Windows command line which seems to be what you are using. (If you happen to have Python installed and in your path, you can do the same test I just did: `python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.write('stdout\n'); sys.stderr.write('stderr\n');"` followed by either `>test.txt 2>&1` or `2>&1 >test.txt`.) The former puts both "stdout" and "stderr" in the file; the latter puts "stdout" in the file and "stderr" on the console.

Comment: For normal tests it works for me too, but this one is different, it uses some compiler specific options to feed the preprocessed files with some adittional information (line numbers, include paths)...

Comment: If I only redirect `stderr` to where `stdout` is put, the errors are shown in console and the .pp file is empty (from the .ii file, I construct the .pp file and this is ok for now). If I redirect `stdout` to the `.ii` files, then `stderr` appears in the `.pp` file.

Comment: So my final assumption is that `stdout` contains the `stderr` too

Comment: Your question and comments refer to `.ii` and `.pp` files, but the actual command line you quote mentions only `.c` and `.i`. Can we focus on the effects of that command, as distinct from whatever later processing is done? If you say `2>&1 `>hello.i`, where does the command's error output go? If you redirect only stderr by saying `2>errors.txt`, where does the error output go? ... Is it possible that `dcc` actually just puts its error output on stdout rather than stderr?

Comment: `2>&1 >hello.i` - error goes in hello.i file .    
`2>errors.txt` - no information .   
That's why I thought as you mentioned that there is a possibility that it just puts it's error output on stdout...
I will mark your answer as accepted because it does answer the question, but this is a special case

Comment: It looks as if [this](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/diab5.0ppc/c-invoke.htm) is documentation for another version of the `dcc` compiler and it seems like it has its own way of redirecting its output. (Search that page for "redirect".) Does that by any chance let you do what you want?